# Possible Conflict with Class name & Property Name?

Tags: c#, class, naming-conventions, namespaces

If you have a namespace that contains a property in ClassA and a class that has the name of that Property somewhere else in your project and both are in the same namespace this won't cause conflicts will it?

So lets say I have a class named Car

```
namespace Dealer
{
   class Vehicle
   {
        // the main class that defines vehicle, so this is Dealer.Vehicle  (Vehicle.cs)
   }
}
```

and a property over in some other class

```
namespace Dealer
{
    class Dealer
    {
        public Vehicle Vehicle
        {
           get { return _vehicle; }
        }
    }
}
```

so for the second it is really this for the property

```
public Dealer.Vehicle Vehicle
{
     get { return _car; }
}
```

so now you have Dealer.Vehicle and Dealer.Dealer.Vehicle.  Wondering of that would cause a conflict ever.

If both those classes are in the same namespace and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
namespace Dealer
{
    class Dealer
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

> Wondering if that would cause a conflict ever.

Yes, that will cause problems. Do not name a class the same as its namespace. [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has written a series of articles about this.

- [Part One: Collisions amongst referenced assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one)
- [Part Two: Machine-generated code](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two)
- [Part Three: Bad hierarchical design](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three)
- [Part Four: Making the problem worse](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four)

Comment: +1 I was about to write the same, and reference the same location.

Comment: I wasn't the one who did that..just wondering. I would never name a class as same as its namespace...it's stupid.  But this is legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, [do not name the class the same as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx).

Second, having a property of the same name as its class will work fine, as I have done it often.